# TFS 2010: Copy _PublishedWebsites to test server

Tags: deployment

I've seen similar questions and answers but found them not really what I want.

I have a large solution with several web projects in it.  All the web projects share some common code so they are all part of the same solution (there is a common project that is referenced by all of them).

I've been running on Team Foundation Server 2008 and we are upgrading to TFS 2010 to be ready for our move to visual studio 2010 and .net 4.0.

I've got the build working with a 2010 build by creating a new build because we only had one customization I'm trying to reproduce.

Once the build is done I have the files dumped at

```
\\SERVER\tfsdump\devel2010 build\devel2010 build_20101008.3\_PublishedWebsites
```

by using the dump folder option but the build location is

```
C:\Builds\1\Web Applications\devel2010 build\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites
```

All I want to do is after the build is finished I want to copy _PublishedWebsites\SiteA  to \ServerA\ShareA
and copy _PublishedWebsites\SiteB  to \ServerB\ShareB

Because there is only one build agent all I need is to call a batch file to run the copy but for easy of use for my developers I need this batch file to be called after every build. Is this possible or is there a better solution?

To make things harder the site is still a 2008 project and it is requested that it stays that way until we can fully test it under VS 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `CopyDirectory` build activity, set `Source` property equal to `BuildDetail.DropLocation + "\_PublishedWebsites\SiteA"` and set `Destination` property to your desired location. I have put this activity as the last activity in build process and it works properly.

Comment: Thank you I ended up with a copy from BinariesDirectory + "\_PublishedWebsites\SiteA" TO   "\\PC\devel2010" To save time and removed turned off the default drop.

Comment: Looks good! Can we go one further and eliminate the hard-coded SiteA directory name? Is there a property on the TFS objects available in TFS build templates that lets you get the web site project name?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from Afshar's answer, for people directly editing XAML template file, create a new sequence after copy to the Drop location is successful:

DisplayName="Something" Source="[BuildDetail.DropLocation + "_PublishedWebsites\SiteA " ]" />

The quotes inside should be written as &quot and semicolon.